# problems when cleaning fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form and keeping all the fields clean, but the  does not answer the instruction $('#txtConductorNew').val('');

the  that do not use the autocomplete property work perfect, it allows you to clean the field in jquery

I would like to know if something of the CSS style or the autocomplete function of the JS that I am using is generating some problem that does not allow to clean the fields.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 autocomplete">
    <label>Conductor</label>
    <input id="txtConductorNew" name="txtConductorNew" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
    font: 16px Arial; 
}
.autocomplete {
    /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.autocomplete-items {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 99;
    /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
    /*when hovering an item:*/
    background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
.autocomplete-active {
    /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
    background-color: #004D27 !important; 
    color: #ffffff; 
}
```

JS

```
function autocomplete(campo, arreglo, campo_oculto) {
    /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
     the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
    var currentFocus;
    /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
    campo.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value;
        /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) {
            return false;
        }
        currentFocus = -1;
        /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        /*for each item in the array...*/
        for (i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
//            if (arreglo[i].nombre.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
            if (arreglo[i].nombre.toUpperCase().includes(val.toUpperCase())) {
                /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
                var posicion_inicial =  arreglo[i].nombre.indexOf(val.toUpperCase());
                var posicion_final =  posicion_inicial + val.length;

                b = document.createElement("DIV");
                /*make the matching letters bold:*/
                b.innerHTML = arreglo[i].nombre.substr(0, posicion_inicial);
                b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arreglo[i].nombre.substring(posicion_inicial, posicion_final) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += arreglo[i].nombre.substr(posicion_final);
                /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
                b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='" + arreglo[i].id + "' value='" + arreglo[i].nombre + "'>";
                /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/

                b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                    campo.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                    campo.id = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id;
                    campo.readOnly = true;
                    campo_oculto.value = campo.id;

                    /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                     (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                    closeAllLists();
                });
                a.appendChild(b);
            }
        }
    });
    /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
    campo.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x)
            x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
             increase the currentFocus variable:*/
            currentFocus++;
            /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
             decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
            currentFocus--;
            /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
                /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
                if (x)
                    x[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });
    function addActive(x) {
        /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
        if (!x)
            return false;
        /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length)
            currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0)
            currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }
    function removeActive(x) {
        /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
         except the one passed as an argument:*/
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != campo) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}
```

JS function clean

```
function clean(){
   $('#txtConductorNew').val('');
}
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("txtConductorNew"), getConductores(), document.getElementById("txtCedulaConductor"));
</script>
```

Comment: clean the fields? What does that mean? Remove the value?

Comment: Yes, Remove the value

Comment: You never use the "clean" function in your code

Comment: if I use it, but when I confirm the save method